# Round double to nearest non subnormal representation

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, floating-point, c++17

In C++ there are (sometimes) [subnormal doubles](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnormal) that are finite, not `nan` and not zero.

How can I round them to nearest non subnormal double representation?

For example: `std::isnormal(DBL_MIN/2.0) = false`

Comment: Interesting question.  Can you give some more detail on why you want to do this?  Wouldn't a series of `if` statements work?

Answer (score 2):

All subnormal double magnitudes are between 0 and `DBL_MIN`. If a value is less than `DBL_MIN`, just round it to one of those, based on comparing it to `DBL_MIN/2`. (To match usual IEEE-754 rounding behavior, `DBL_MIN/2` itself should be rounded to 0.)

Comment: Half of the subnormal values are between `-DBL_MIN` and zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, I decided to leave that as an epiphany for the reader.

Comment: Both `DBL_MIN` and 0 have an even significand.  While 0 is of course infinitely even, I don’t know a rule to pick between them here.

Comment: @DavisHerring My thinking was that 0 had a more purely zero significand than DBL_MIN; the regular rounding rules, and the rules for rounding to integer, prefer results with more trailing zeroes. But I agree that the rules aren't explicitly extended there.